# Add item to asyncio queue from a request handler

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, pynetdicom

I have a TCP server running and have a handler function which needs to take the contents of the request, add it to an asyncio queue and reply with an OK status.

On the background I have an async coroutine running that detects when a new item is added and performs some processing.

**How do I put items in the asyncio queue from the handler function, which isn't and can't be an async coroutine?**

I am running a DICOM server [pynetdicom](https://github.com/pydicom/pynetdicom) which listens on port 104 for incoming TCP requests (DICOM `C-STORE` specifically).

I need to save the contents of the request to a queue and return a a `0x0000` response so that the listener is available to the network.

This is modeled by a producer-consumer pattern.

I have tried to define a consumer co-routine `consume_dicom()` that is currently stuck in `await queue.get()` since I can't properly define the producer.

The producer needs to simply invoke `queue.put(produce_item)` but this happens inside a `handle_store(event)` function which is not part of the `event_loop` but is called every time a request is received by the server.

```py
import asyncio

from pynetdicom import (
    AE, evt,
    StoragePresentationContexts
)

class PacsServer():
    def __init__(self, par, listen=True):
        # Initialize other stuff...

        # Initialize DICOM server
        ae = AE(ae_title='DICOM-NODE')
        ae.supported_contexts = StoragePresentationContexts

        # When a C-STORE request comes, it will be passed to self.handle_store
        handlers = [(evt.EVT_C_STORE, self.handle_store)]

        # Define queue
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)

        # Define consumer
        loop.create_task(self.consume_dicom(self.queue))

        # Start server in the background with specified handlers
        self.scp = ae.start_server(('', 104), block=False, evt_handlers=handlers)

        # Start async loop
        self.loop.run_forever()



    def handle_store(self, event):
        # Request handling
        ds = event.dataset

        # Here I want to add to the queue but this is not an async method
        await queue.put(ds)

        return 0x0000


    async def consume_dicom(self, queue):
        while True:
            print(f"AWAITING FROM QUEUE")
            ds = await queue.get()

            do_some_processing(ds)
```

I would like to find a way to add items to the queue and return the OK status in the `handle_store()` function.

Comment: Try changing `await queue.put(ds)` to `self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, ds)`

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly and with no errors of any kind, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `handle_store` is running in a different thread, it needs to tell the event loop to enqueue the item. This is done with [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe):

```
self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, ds)
```

Note that you need to call [`queue.put_nowait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.put_nowait) instead of `queue.put` because the former is a function rather than a coroutine. The function will always succeed for unbounded queues (the default), otherwise it will raise an exception if the queue is full.